# How to use python io library to write on to an external file

Tags: python, file-io

I am currently using the python io library to write in to an external file. Below is a sample piece of code which i am trying to execute:

```
import io
output=io.StringIO
output.write('\n Hello world ')
output.close()
print output.getvalue()
```

when I run this piece of code i get an error. Can any one tell me where I am going wrong and whats the reason for the error.

Comment: How about you tell us what the error is.

Comment: Also, the StringIO class doesn't write anything to files. It's only an in-memory representation.

Comment: You're getting the error because, as it says in `StringIO`'s [`getvalue()` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html?highlight=getvalue#StringIO.StringIO.getvalue), you need to call it *before* calling the corresponding `StringIO` object’s `close()` method. The reason being that the internal string buffer that holds the data written to `StringIO` object is freed when you call `close()`. Note also that using `StringIO` is *not* the same as writing data to an external file -- everything kept in a memory buffer instead.

Answer (score 6):

`StringIO` is for writing to strings, treating them as in-memory streams.

If you want to write to file, do this:

```
f = open('yourfile', 'w')
f.write('Hello, world.')
f.close()
```

No need to use `StringIO` for this.

You did not even get an instance of the class, because there aren't parentheses `()` after `StringIO`, so your variable pointed to the `StringIO` class, and I'm quite sure that is not what you wanted to do.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Andrea. However, if you need to do it your way:

```
import cStringIO
output=cStringIO.StringIO()

output.write('\n Hello world ')

print output.getvalue()
output.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of uses for StringIO, for instance it can be used in place of a mutable string.  However since your goal is to write to file, you should skip it and just go straight to file:

```
with open('file/path', 'w') as fh:
    fh.write('Hello World!')

print open('file/path').read() # if you need to actually print it out.
```

Answer (score 0):

That bit of code has various problems.

First, you have assigned a class to out instead of an instance. Try `out = io.StringIO()` instead.

Second, unless you're running Python v3 the write method will complain your are using acsii instead of unicode.

Thirdly, you attempt to read from out after you have closed it. As martineau said, StringIO does not allow to retrieve output after close has been called. Slightly confusing if you're coming from a Java background where close in the corresponding class (StringWriter) has no effect.

Finally, StringIO writes to memory and not to file. Use `out = open(filename,'w')` if you want to write to file.

So without knowing the exact error your received, that's all I got. Posting the error you receive is normally pretty useful.